# Reading from a text file and storing in a 2D array

Tags: c

I've been trying to store a matrix input in a txt file in a array but it show me this:
this is the code

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, j, row, col, nl, cr;

    row = col = nl = cr = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("g.txt", "r");

    // Figure out how many rows and columns the text file has
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            nl++;
        if (c == '\r')
            cr++;

        col++;

        if (c == '\n')
            row++;

       putchar(c);
    }

    col = (col - (nl + cr));
    col = (int) (col/row);

   // printf("\nnumber of rows is %d\n", row);


    // read letters into array

    char array[row][col];

    if ( fp )
       {
        for ( ;; )
              {
            c = getc(fp);
                 if ( c == EOF )
                 {
                        break;
                 }
                 if ( c != '\n' && c != '\r' )
                 {
                        array[i][j] = c;

                    if ( ++j >= col )
                        {
                            j = 0;
                            if ( ++i >= row )
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
            for ( j = 0; j < col; j++ )
            {
                 putchar( array[i][j]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

somone have any idea please?
exemple of the txt file :

```
255  50  9  50  1  50  50  1
50  255  50  50  50  50  50 50
50  50  255  50  50  50 50  50
8  50  50  255  50 50  50  50
50  50  50  50 255 50  50  50
50  50  50 50  50  255  50  50
1  50 50  50  50  50  255  50
2 50  50  50  50  50  50  255
```

my program show me this:

```
255 50   9   50  1   50   50   1
50  255  50  50  50  50   50   50
50  50   255 50  50  50   50   50
8   50   50  255 50  50   50   50
50  50   50  50  255 50   50   50
50  50   50  50  50  255  50   50
1   50   50  50  50  50   255  50
2   50   50  50  50  50   50   255     $■( 1gÍuáþ09■   ı¤ıu"ÒávD   ê$[
►  ð²(     ♥       l    ►      ■   
  ê$[ ♥   l       ­²( O»ƒv[ 4■( Qõá
v♥   #õáv┬²║Oÿ|®v    ñ|®ve┬ív
 ■(     x■( ÿ|®v Ó²⌂    @■(  áƒv╚♀[ L
■( w¯ƒv‼   ê■( I┴ávÿ|®v↓┴áv~²║O
   Ó²⌂    \■( ■   ─ ( e┬ívÍ┬29►☺
```

for the input file it show the good one ,but the problem is for the array output i don't undrestand why it show me this caracters

Comment: where is 2D array in your code?

Comment: On a side note the line `double atof ( const char * str );`is not needed as the function already is declared in stdlib.h. Your code actually won't compile with that line present in my compiler.

Comment: double numbers[100][100];

Comment: you never change the j variable when you read data from file

Comment: @Butterflay After the edit the code won't compile as the argument to fgets and atoi is incorrect; they take char* not char[][].

Comment: sorry i don't undrestand what is the problem ,i don't undrestand english very well

Comment: firstly try to write operation sequnce (algorithm) on your natural language: 1. open file 2. until the end of file read line from file incrementing the totalLines variable 3. split each line on parts separated by the space character and assign it to the matrix cell and only after that you have to translate that on concrete machine language

Comment: thank u for your answer it's exactly what i try to do

Comment: @Butterflay Don't re-post the same question with a sockpuppet account. [Image.](http://imgur.com/gwioITt)

Answer (score 3):

You never change j, it always remains 0, so you're writing every position a[i][0]. atoi(line); will convert the first number in the line only. That's why your program is only storing the first column.

A possible approach to fix this would be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int  i=0,totalNums,totalNum,j=0;
    size_t count;
    int numbers[100][100];
    char *line = malloc(100);

    FILE *file;  /* declare a FILE pointer  */
    file = fopen("g.txt", "r");  /* open a text file for reading */

    while(getline(&line, &count, file)!=-1) {
        for (; count > 0; count--, j++)
            sscanf(line, "%d", &numbers[i][j]);
        i++;
    }

    totalNums = i;
    totalNum = j;
    for (i=0 ; i<totalNums ; i++) {
      for (j=0 ; j<totalNum ; j++) {
        printf("\n%d",  numbers[i][j]);
      }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

That code will read the entire line, and then parse it number by number until no more numbers are there.

I didn't really understand if input is supposed to be integers or doubles, note that you declare a 2D array of doubles but then you call atoi(). The code I posted assumes it's integers, but then make sure to change your array to a 2D array of ints (or if they really are doubles, change the format string in sscanf).

Comment: thank u for ur answer ,i compile it with the new code but i have a black consol it show nothing :(

Comment: @Butterflay you're right, sorry, my bad. sscanf() was blocking because of newline characters in the end. I edited my answer and the code now works, I tested it.

Comment: soryy i have error getline was not defined

Comment: did you include stdio.h?

Comment: yeah of course i add it

Comment: well, it compiles here with gcc using -Wall... getline is defined in stdio.h

Comment: the exact error is undefined reference to `getline'

Comment: i use codeblocks in windows to compile

Comment: give a look at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/253585/using-the-getline-function

Comment: i change the code can you look at this solution please?

Comment: you deleted your entire post

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  FILE * fp;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

  const char *s = " ";
  char *token = NULL;

  int i = 0;
  double arr[200];
  int j;

  fp = fopen("g.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error opening");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while ((read=getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
  {
     token = strtok(line, s);

     while(token != NULL)
     {
       arr[i] = atoi(token);
       printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
       token=strtok(NULL,s);
       i++;
     }
  }

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  return 0;
}
```

`getline` will read file line by line and `strtok` will split entries based on space and will store seperately entries in array. Also single dimensional array is enough to store values.

Comment: thank u but a have many errors after compile it

Comment: @Butterflay, are you including the header files? Also run it as a seperate fresh program

Comment: yeah of course i add the header files

Comment: i have error getline was not defined

Comment: @Butterflay, may be you are using different compiler, just include #define _GNU_SOURCE. i did the edit.

Comment: i use  #define _GNU_SOURCE but i have always the same error:(