# Read matrix from text file and store it in array 2D

Tags: c

I've been trying to store a matrix input in a text file in an array but it shows me peculiar output.  This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, j, row, col, nl, cr;

    row = col = nl = cr = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("g.txt", "r");

    // Figure out how many rows and columns the text file has
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            nl++;
        if (c == '\r')
            cr++;

        col++;

        if (c == '\n')
            row++;

       putchar(c);
    }

    col = (col - (nl + cr));
    col = (int) (col/row);

   // printf("\nnumber of rows is %d\n", row);


    // read letters into array

    char array[row][col];

    if ( fp )
       {
        for ( ;; )
              {
            c = getc(fp);
                 if ( c == EOF )
                 {
                        break;
                 }
                 if ( c != '\n' && c != '\r' )
                 {
                        array[i][j] = c;

                    if ( ++j >= col )
                        {
                            j = 0;
                            if ( ++i >= row )
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
            for ( j = 0; j < col; j++ )
            {
                 putchar( array[i][j]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example of the data file:

```
255  50  9  50  1  50  50  1
50  255  50  50  50  50  50 50
50  50  255  50  50  50 50  50
8  50  50  255  50 50  50  50
50  50  50  50 255 50  50  50
50  50  50 50  50  255  50  50
1  50 50  50  50  50  255  50
2 50  50  50  50  50  50  255
```

My program shows me this output:

```
255 50   9   50  1   50   50   1
50  255  50  50  50  50   50   50
50  50   255 50  50  50   50   50
8   50   50  255 50  50   50   50
50  50   50  50  255 50   50   50
50  50   50  50  50  255  50   50
1   50   50  50  50  50   255  50
2   50   50  50  50  50   50   255     $■( 1gÍuáþ09■   ı¤ıu"ÒávD   ê$[
►  ð²(     ♥       l    ►      ■   
  ê$[ ♥   l       ­²( O»ƒv[ 4■( Qõá
v♥   #õáv┬²║Oÿ|®v    ñ|®ve┬ív
 ■(     x■( ÿ|®v Ó²⌂    @■(  áƒv╚♀[ L
■( w¯ƒv‼   ê■( I┴ávÿ|®v↓┴áv~²║O
   Ó²⌂    \■( ■   ─ ( e┬ívÍ┬29►☺
```

for the input file shown, but the problem is for the array output I don't understand why it show me these characters.

Comment: I'm sure this line : `char array[row][col];` can't compile, an array declared on stack must have a fixed size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from a text file and storing in a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942719/reading-from-a-text-file-and-storing-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: [this](http://imgur.com/gwioITt). Are you working on the same assignment? Or is this a sockpuppet account?

Comment: yeah it's a same subject but isn't a duplicate ,the other one i can compile it because of my old pc

Comment: @Michael: if the code is compiled with a C99 or C11 compiler, the code shown is fine; the array is a _variable length array_ or VLA.  In C90, you'd be correct, but C90 hasn't been the current standard for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Michael's comment is correct, I'd be surprised if that even compiles. You'll need to allocate your array dynamically, like so:

```
char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * row)
```

And each row like:

`array[c] = malloc(sizeof(char) * col)`

You'll have to free each row and the array with free as well.

It also looks like you are trying read and store integer values. Keep in mind when you do get this working you'll still have to convert the character values if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
FILE *fopen(), *fp;
char c;
int i=0,j=0;
char file[50][50];
fp = fopen("abc.txt","r");
c = getc(fp) ;
while (c!= EOF)
{
file[i][j]=c;

    j++;
    c = getc(fp);

    if(j==50){
    i++;
    j=0;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: @ rahul i already test this code it doesn't work ,can you check my code please i just have a problem to show array

Comment: @Butterflay:- Have you checked the solution given in this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942719/reading-from-a-text-file-and-storing-in-a-2d-array ????

Comment: it's me ,and it's the same one