# How to load a text file with fixed dimensions into a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have fixed contents like this in a text file, and a 2D array with the same dimensions ([4][4]).

```
   0200 
   0300 
   0060 
   0000
```

I've tried this:

```
   char board[4][4];
   FILE *myFile;
   myFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");

   for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
       {
           fscanf(myFile, "%s", &board[i][j]);
       }
   }

   for(i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
       for(j=0; j<4; j++)
       {
           printf("%s", &board[i][j]);
       }
   }
```

But it doesn't output correctly.

Comment: Please add some code that shows your attempt at doing it.

Comment: @BoR I have done so

Comment: " fixed contents like this in a text file" is the file always space separated digits?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry no, I've updated the post. It's not space seperated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading from a text file and storing in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942719/reading-from-a-text-file-and-storing-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate since this one isn't space separated or otherwise delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%c` and add a space to ignore whitespace line `\n`.

```c
         fscanf(myFile, " %c", &board[i][j]);
```

and the second

```c
      for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
         printf("%c", board[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
```

Comment: This answers my question, however after using this, instead of the ASCII e.g. '0' I want the actual integer 0 in the array. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @A444433232, after the `fscanf` row add `board[i][j] -= '0';`. When printing you might want to change it to `printf("%d ", (int) board[i][j]);`. Remember, this solution will only work with values 0-9. Since there are no separators between the digits.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I am only using values 0-3, so that's not a problem.